# Output of a Stack, Queue, and LinkedList brain teaser

Tags: java, stack, queue

This is a problem from a book testing you on LinkedLists, Stacks, and Queue. The goal is to print out the desired output from this short snippet of code. I have accompanied the code with my analysis.

```
LinkedList<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

a.add( 2 );
a.add( 3 );
a.add( 5 );
a.add( 7 );
```

The LL: `a = {2, 3, 5, 7}`

```
for ( int i : a )
{
    System.out.print( i + " " );
    s.push( i );
    q.add( i );
}
```

print output: `2 3 5 7`

The stack: `s = {2, 3, 5, 7}`

The queue: `q = {2, 3, 5, 7}`

```
System.out.println();

for ( int i : a )
{
    s.push( i );
    q.add( s.pop() + 5 );
    System.out.print( s.pop() + " " );
}
```

The stack: `s = {2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7}`

The queue: `q = {2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 10, 8, 7}`. This is as a result of `s.pop() + 5`

Print output: `7 5 3 2`

```
System.out.println();

for ( int i : a )
{
    System.out.print( q.remove() + " " );
    System.out.print( q.remove() + " " );
}
```

Print output: `2 3 5 7 12 10 8 7`

So in summary, my print outputs are:

`2 3 5 7`

`7 5 3 2`

`2 3 5 7 12 10 8 7`

The answer to this problem, however, is this:

`2 3 5 7`

`7 5 3 2`

`2 3 5 7 7 8 10 12`

As you can see, the results don't match in the queue printing. I redid the problem twice, but could not determine whether I did something wrong in the addition (`s.pop() + 5`) or in my `.pop()` printing. Could someone give me some insight on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your mistake is here, in the third code snippet:

```
for ( int i : a )
{
    s.push( i );
    q.add( s.pop() + 5 );
    System.out.print( s.pop() + " " );
}
```

After `i` is pushed onto the stack, it is *immediately popped off* by `q.add(s.pop() + 5);`. Execution would go something like this:

Before:

```
s == [2, 3, 5, 7]
q == [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

First iteration:

```
2 is pushed onto s
2 is popped off of s
5 is added to 2
7 is added to q
7 is popped off s and printed
```

Second iteration:

```
3 is pushed onto s
3 is popped off of s
5 is added to 3
8 is added to q
5 is popped off s and printed
```

And so on and so forth.

So the proper result after that loop should be an empty stack and a queue that is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```

Everything else is OK, I think.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage No problem! Just a tip -- you can always type the code into an IDE and use a debugger to see exactly is going on for things like this.

Comment: Actually, could you explain a little in depth what is going on at `q.add(s.pop()+5)`? Which gets executed first, is it `q.add` or `s.pop()` or `s.pop() + 5`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Just updated my answer. The arguments for an operation/method are always evaluated before the operation/method is executed. So before `q.add()` can be called, `s.pop() + 5` has to be evaluated. And before `+` can be evaluated, `s.pop()` and `5` have to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These order of operations were what got me, thank you again user :).

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is the best way to do these on paper? I don't want to rely too much on the IDE for conceptual questions like this.

Comment: You know what, actually, I get it. `s.pop() + 5` getting evaluated first, then added to `q`. Makes perfect sense. Thank you A LOT.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Best way to do these on paper is to pretend you're a computer! Just go line by line doing exactly what the code tells you to do, breaking down things, following method calls, etc. as much as you need to. I can't really be more specific than that, unfortunately (that's all I usually have to think about when I do this kind of thing), but as long as you clear your head of any preconceptions about what the code is supposed to do you'll generally do fine.